# How to get this slideshow to automatically rotate

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/CkuKe/

It works beautifully, but only when prev/next is clicked. Can it be persuaded to run automatically as well?

Comment: Please include the code in your question, and not just a link. If jsFiddle goes down, your question is left incomplete. How should the "automatic" run interact with the next/prev buttons? Make the buttons irrelevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated code to auto slide after clicking on #next/#prev.

Note: After clicking on the `#next/#prev`, the autoSlide is called after 2 secs to make.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/CkuKe/10/)

```
/* home slide show */

var $slides = $('.slideshow_item');
var slide_pos = 0;
var slide_len = $('.slideshow_item').length;
var slide_int = 0;

$slides.filter(':gt(0)').hide();

autoSlide();

function autoSlide() {
    slide_pos = 0;
    slide_int = setInterval(function() {
        $slides.eq(slide_pos % slide_len).fadeOut(500);
        $slides.eq(++slide_pos % slide_len).fadeIn(500);
    }, 500);
}

$('#next').click(function() {
    $slides.eq(slide_pos % slide_len).fadeOut(500);
    $slides.eq(++slide_pos % slide_len).fadeIn(500);

    clearInterval(slide_int);
    setTimeout(autoSlide, 2000);
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    $slides.eq(slide_pos % slide_len).fadeOut(500);
    $slides.eq(--slide_pos % slide_len).fadeIn(500);

    clearInterval(slide_int);
    setTimeout(autoSlide, 2000);
});
```

---

Just add that 2 line of code that you have `#next` inside the setInterval.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/CkuKe/3/)

```
slide_int = setInterval(function() {
    $slides.eq(slide_pos % slide_len).fadeOut(500);
    $slides.eq(++slide_pos % slide_len).fadeIn(500);
}, 500);
```

Comment: After clicking prev/next it stops being automatic again.

Comment: @Andy So how do you want it to behave after clicking Next/Prev. Just need to move that setInterval inside a function and call that from #next and #prev using setTimeout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to proceed again with the counter starting at 0.

Comment: That second link seems to break after repeated clicks of Next or Previous.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You were mostly correct in calling the click handler every 500ms, but the `clearInterval`  was stopping it after the first iteration.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CkuKe/9/)**

```
    /* home slide show */

var $slides = $('.slideshow_item');
var slide_pos = 0;
var slide_len = $('.slideshow_item').length;

$slides.filter(':gt(0)').hide();

slide_int = setInterval(function() {
    $('#next').click();
}, 500);

$('#next').click(function() {
    $slides.eq(slide_pos % slide_len).fadeOut(500);
    $slides.eq(++slide_pos % slide_len).fadeIn(500);

    //clearInterval(slide_int);
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
    $slides.eq(slide_pos % slide_len).fadeOut(500);
    $slides.eq(--slide_pos % slide_len).fadeIn(500);

    //clearInterval(slide_int);
});​
```

Comment: Nice, one thing I noticed however. When I click previous/next, it doesn't reset the timer.

Comment: If you want it to, then you need to call `clearInterval`, and then re-initialize `slide_int`. you can do this by wrapping the `setInterval` statement in a function, and calling it after calling `clearInterval`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll have a play with it.